# Can't receive KeyEvent when enable accessibility function on Custom View on Android

Tags: android, accessibility

For Android Accessibility, i want to use volume down/up to make custom view value increase or decrease. I override onKeyDown method in custom view, but i can't receive any key event when press volume down/up.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        boolean increment;
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS:
                increment = false;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PLUS:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_EQUALS:
                increment = true;
                changeValueByOne(increment);
                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```